# why mutex didn't lock the variable

Tags: c, mutex

```
#define N 20
static pthread_mutex_t lock = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

void *thread_main(void* arg){
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);  
    long * i = (long*)arg;
    printf("%ld\n", *i);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
    return NULL;
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t tid[N];
    int rc;
    
    for (long i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        rc = pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, thread_main, &i);
        if (rc) {
            fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: could not create thread\n");
            return -1;
        }
    }
    
---thread join---

}
```

in this code my out put is

7
7
7
7
7
7
8
9
10
10
6
12
13
14
20
20
20
20
20
20

not sure why it didn't lock long i and print it as:

0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19

what's the problem and that is the strategy to solve this condition

Answer (score 1):

The variable is modified by the `for` loop, but that thread does not hold the mutex. The mutex didn't lock the variable because you modified the variable without holding the lock.

Comment: so u mean use lock in for loop to lock the pthread_create ? so that &i can be locked?

Comment: @TomZhang It depends on exactly what you're trying to do, which you don't tell us. But you do have a race condition because one thread can modify `i` while another thread is accessing that. You need to fix all race conditions before doing anything else.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing the mutex around the print function.

This means that only one thing will print at once, but that's not really helpful. The value of `i` can still change because `i++` is outside the mutex.

You probably the changes to `i` to happen inside the mutex.

I suspect this is what you want:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define N 20
static pthread_mutex_t lock = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

void *thread_main(void* arg){
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);  
    long *i = (long*)arg;
    // Modifications to i happen inside the mutex
    printf("%ld\n", (*i)++);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
    return NULL;
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t tid[N];
    int rc;
    long i = 0;
    
    // For/while loop does not modify value of i directly
    while (i < N) {
        rc = pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, thread_main, &i);
        if (rc) {
            fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: could not create thread\n");
            return -1;
        }
    }
}
```